# Unable to access parameters from union types (TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, typescript

Why am not able to access attributes in union types like this:

```
export interface ICondition {
  field: string
  operator: string
  value: string
}

export interface IConditionGroup {
  conditions: ICondition[]
  group_operator: string
}

function foo(item: ICondition | IConditionGroup) {
  if(typeof item.conditions === "undefined") { // does not work
    let field = item.field; // does not work
    ///.. do something 
  } else {
    let conditions = item.conditions; // does not work
    /// .. do something else
  }
}
```

I get these errors:

```
error TS2339: Property 'conditions' does not exist on type 'ICondition | IConditionGroup'.
error TS2339: Property 'conditions' does not exist on type 'ICondition | IConditionGroup'.
error TS2339: Property 'field' does not exist on type 'ICondition | IConditionGroup'.
```

But I have to cast types to get it to work - like this:

```
function foo2(inputItem: ICondition | IConditionGroup) {
  if(typeof (<IConditionGroup>inputItem).conditions === "undefined") {
    let item= (<ICondition>inputItem);
    let field = item.field;
    ///.. do something 
  } else {
    let item= (<IConditionGroup>inputItem);
    let conditions = item.conditions;
    /// .. do something else
  }
}
```

I understand that the type information is lost in JS, so why do I have to explicitly cast it in TS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typescript handles this with [Type Guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types), usually it's as simple as:

```
if (typeof item === "string") { ... } else { ... }
```

Or

```
if (item instanceof MyClass) { ... } else { ... }
```

But in your case as you're using interfaces that's not possible, so you'll need to create your own [User-Defined Type Guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```
function isConditionGroup(item: ICondition | IConditionGroup): item is IConditionGroup {
    return (item as IConditionGroup).conditions !== undefined;
}

function foo(item: ICondition | IConditionGroup) {
    if (isConditionGroup(item)) {
        let conditions = item.conditions;
        // do something
    } else {
        let field = item.field;
        // do something else
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20interface%20ICondition%20%7B%0D%0A%09field%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%09operator%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%09value%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20IConditionGroup%20%7B%0D%0A%09conditions%3A%20ICondition%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%09group_operator%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20isConditionGroup(item%3A%20ICondition%20%7C%20IConditionGroup)%3A%20item%20is%20IConditionGroup%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(item%20as%20IConditionGroup).conditions%20!%3D%3D%20undefined%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20foo(item%3A%20ICondition%20%7C%20IConditionGroup)%20%7B%0D%0A%09if%20(isConditionGroup(item))%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09let%20conditions%20%3D%20item.conditions%3B%0D%0A%09%09%2F%2F%20do%20something%0D%0A%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09let%20field%20%3D%20item.field%3B%0D%0A%09%09%2F%2F%20do%20something%20else%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D))

You can also do it without type guards:

```
function foo(item: ICondition | IConditionGroup) {
    if ((item as IConditionGroup).conditions !== undefined) {
        let conditions = (item as IConditionGroup).conditions;
        // do something
    } else {
        let field = (item as ICondition).field;
        // do something else
    }
}
```

But that's way to verbose as you need to type assert `item` 3 times instead of once.